# xslt convert attributes to new elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert a simple xml to structured xml using xslt.

This is my xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <foo bar="12" baz="34">ONE</foo>
```

And this is what I want:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <foo>
  <a> 
   <a> 
    <a>bar</a>
    <v>12</v> 
  </a> 
 <a>   
    <a>baz</a>     
    <v>34</v>   
 </a>
```

```
<v>ONE</v> 
</foo>
```

The “foo” element contains two attributes, “bar” and “baz” and the value of the element “ONE”. In the converted format, the element foo will contain an attributes sequence “a” which will contain a sequence-of attribute “a”.

The attribute  sequence-of will contain “a” and “v” element which will be the name and value of the attribute respectively. All the attributes of the foo element are contained inside the attributes sequence. The value of foo is places inside a “v” element after the attribute sequence.
I can break attributes to elements but I don't know how to add new element.

Comment: The example seems to be too contrived to give an answer comfortably. Does the `<foo>` element in the output take its name from the input, or can it be hard-coded?

Comment: Also, the output has more `<a>` opening tags than closing ones.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <v><xsl:value-of select="."/></v> 
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
<a> 
    <a><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></a>
    <v><xsl:value-of select="."/></v> 
</a> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo bar="12" baz="34">ONE</foo>
```

the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
  <a>
    <a>bar</a>
    <v>12</v>
  </a>
  <a>
    <a>baz</a>
    <v>34</v>
  </a>
  <v>ONE</v>
</foo>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur solution....to answer ur question foo takes its name from the input. My main goal is to break input attributes to pieces of small elements....Thanks again...